# How to stop an animation with button click event

Tags: java

Hi can anybody help below is a piece of code im trying to implement a click event that when a button is clicked the animation will start and can be stop whenever you want to. It works fine for starting the animation only the stopping is giving an issue

```
public class AnimateCircleListener implements ActionListener,MouseListener
 {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if(e.getSource() == button)
        {
           flag = true;

           if(flag == true)
          {
              // creates thread object and calls the move method
              Move move = new Move();
              thread = new Thread(move);
              thread.start();

          }

        }
     }

           @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {



            }


            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {


            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {


        }

  }

    public class Move implements Runnable  // method for moving ball
    {
     public void run()
     {
        do
        {
            x = x + xvel;

            if(x + diameter > 484)
            xvel= -1;

            if(x <= 0)
            xvel =  + 1;

            drawPanel.repaint();

            try
              {
              Thread.sleep(10);
              }
               catch(Exception ex)
              {
                  System.out.println("Error");
              }

          }while(decide);  // by default decide = true

       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the animation.

Then you can just invoke the `start()` method in your Start button and the `stop()` method in your Stop button.